# Brownian Motion - Probability of two times

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

Let {B(t), t ≥ 0} be a standard Brownian motion. Show that
$$ P(B(s)>0, B(t)<0)= \int_{0}^{\infty}\Phi(-\sqrt{s\over{t-s}}y)φ(y)dy$$
for any 0 < s < t, where φ and Φ are the p.d.f. and c.d.f. of standard normal, respectively.

I have tried to approach this problem by suggesting that B(t) follows N(0,t)
I have also searched in the textbook and they suggested to change $$Pr⁡(B(s)>0,B(t)<0)=Pr⁡(B(s)>0,B(s)+B(t)-B(s)<0)$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}Pr⁡(B(s)>0,B(s)+B(t)-B(s)<0 |B(s)=y) {1\over\sqrt{2π}} \mathrm{e}^{-y^2\over2} dy $$
I would like to know why the second step can be done so?

Comment: You mean how the last integral comes up? It is a continuous version of law of total probability - you conditioned on the value of $B(s)$. It is a common and very useful technique.